# Javascript confirm box, yes/no, it shows confirm box but never waits for the use to hit Yes. it automatically submits the form

Tags: javascript

Javascript code:

```
   if (s12.value < s10.value) {
       $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
           .html('<div><h6>' + "Out Time is less than In Time. Is that ok??" + '</h6></div>')
           .dialog({
               modal: true,
               title: 'Confirmation',
               zIndex: 10000,
               autoOpen: true,
               width: 'auto',
               resizable: true,
               buttons: {
                   Yes: function () {
                       if (s10.value < s14.value || s14.value < s12.value) {
                           alertDialog("Time is not between out time and in time.");
                       } else {
                           $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").submit();
                       }
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   },
                   No: function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               },
               close: function (event, ui) {
                   $(this).remove();
               }
           });

       < script >
           function alertDialog(message) {
               $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                   .html('<div><h6>' + message + '</h6></div>')
                   .dialog({
                       modal: true,
                       title: 'Errors',
                       zIndex: 10000,
                       autoOpen: true,
                       width: 'auto',
                       resizable: true,
                       buttons: {
                           Ok: function () {

                               $(this).dialog("close");
                           },

                       },
                       close: function (event, ui) {
                           $(this).remove();
                       }
                   });
       }; < /script>
```

Condition 1: `if (s12.value < s10.value)` then display confirm box saying "Out Time is less than In Time. Is that ok??"

if user selects Yes then Condition 2: `if (s10.value < s14.value || s14.value < s12.value)` then display alert box

else Submit the form.

Problem: It is able to show confirm box but never waits for the user to hit Yes/No, it automatically submits the form.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you indented your code properly and told us what all the `s**.value` stuff was, maybe we would be able to help ?

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: If it's being run from a form's `submit` handler, you need to return false from that to prevent the default form submission, and have your `Yes` code in the modal call `form.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should create dialog without open

```
 var dialog_var = $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
 .html('<div><h6>' + message + '</h6></div>')
 .dialog({
 modal: true, title: 'Errors', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
 width: 'auto', resizable: true,
 buttons: {
 Ok: function () {
   $(this).dialog("close");
 },


function alertDialog(message) {
  $(dialog_var).dialog("open");
```

Comment: s10.value --> Patient In Time
s12.value --> Patient Out time
s14.value --> Procedure Time (in between Patient In Time and Out time)
example : if Patient IN time --> 22:00
Patient  out Time : 5:00
then Procedure time should be between 22:00 and 5:00 like 3:00